# Милкшейк / милк шейк

Tags: слитно-раздельно

В интернете видел слитное написание — `милкшейк`.

В меню одного ресторана было написано раздельно — `милк шейк`.

Мне кажется, надо слитно. Даже в английском пишем milkshake, то есть слитно, но там почему-то раздельно.

А вы как думаете? Думаю, ошибка и нужно писать слитно.

Comment: если грамотно, то через дефис - милк-шейк. А вообще это же транслит, так что milkshake